# UI-Router - What is the exact issue for the getting the error as `Maximum call stack size exceeded'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My app have the login page, which require to redirect to another extenal web site. as well I require to use the same login page with another new `state` name.

i have made the required changes, But I am getting the error as

`Maximum call stack size exceeded` - which I am not able to understand at all. how to overcome with this?

here is my code :

state provider stuff : both are same login controller and html

```
$stateProvider
      .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl as ctrl',
        data: {
          requireLogin: false
        }
      })
      .state('fallback', {
        url: '/fallback',
        templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl as ctrl',
        data: {
          requireLogin: false
        }
      })
```

issue :

```
function stateController($rootScope,  $state,  fsErr ){
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams ) {


      if( toState.name === 'login' ){

        window.location = 'https://cway.cisco.com/fs/';
        event.preventDefault();

      }

      if( toState.name === 'fallback' ){

        console.log('nothing doing') //consoles 1227 times
        $state.go("fallback");
        event.preventDefault();

        return false;

      }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

This is similar to an infinite loop. The `$state.go("fallback");` is getting called infintly and hence causing the error.

Here is the problem:
The `$stateChangeStart` will trigger whenever there is $state changes. So here when the $state is changing to **fallback**, IF `true`, then again call  `$state.go("fallback");` which will trigger `stateChangeStart` again, and starts looping.

Solution:

1. You can simply delete the else if block:

   ```
   if( toState.name === 'fallback' && !loop) {
       console.log('nothing doing');
       $state.go("fallback");
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
   } //delete this if statement
   ```
2. Set a flag and break the loop.

var loop; // to be defined in parent function outside the $rootScope.$on.

```
if( toState.name === 'fallback' && !loop) {
    loop = true
    console.log('nothing doing')
    $state.go("fallback");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I understand this logic, But still I am getting the same issue

Comment: After deleting the second if block completely also?

Comment: Or if you are tring to use flag to exit the loop, then declare the varible before $rootScope.$on function.